# Replace duplicate char in array

Tags: java, arrays, replace, duplicates, character

Given an array of unsorted characters for e.g. `'a', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'b'`. What is the best way to sort and remove duplicates characters with empty spaces and shift the empty spaces to end of array. e.g. `'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ' ', ' ';` without using additional buffer, memory or collections api in Java?

Answer (score 1):

```
   public void checkduplicate()
    {
         char chnew =' ';
         char[] ch ={ 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b' , 'a', 'b'};

         for(int i =0 ; i<ch.length;i++)
         {                        
             for(int j =i+1 ;j<ch.length;j++)
             {

                 if(ch [j]== ch[i] )
                 {
                     ch[j] = ' ';
                 }
              if(ch[j] <ch[i] && ch[j] != ' ' )
             {
                 chnew = ch[i];            
                 ch[i] = ch[j];
                 ch[j] = chnew;                                
             }

             }

         }
         for(int k=0;k<ch.length;k++)
         {
             System.out.println(ch[k]);
         }

     }
```

Comment: look like you missed this part of the question :) `shift the empty spaces to end of array`

Comment: its absolutely works fine for shifting empty spaces to end of array

Comment: check this scenario `char[] ch ={ 'a', 'a','c', 'd', 'b' , 'a', 'b'};`